# What is stopping FACTORING from being BQP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, shors-algorithm, bqp

Classical complexity theory makes much of the study of so-called *[intermediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate)* problems - that is, problems that are in $\mathsf{NP}$ but are nonetheless not known to be in $\mathsf{P}$ and further not expected to be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

Commonly discussed examples of likely intermediate problems include, e.g., GRAPH-ISOMORPHISM and FACTORING.  One reason why GRAPH-ISOMORPHISM and FACTORING are both thought to be of intermediate complexity is that neither are known to have an algorithm in $\mathsf{BPP}$, while both are known to be in $\mathsf{coNP}$ (or rather, $\mathsf{coAM}$ in the case of GRAPH-ISOMPORPHISM) - thus if, for example, FACTORING/GRAPH-ISOMPORPHISM were $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, then one would have the conclusion that $\mathsf{NP=coNP}$/the polynomial-time hierarchy $\mathsf{PH}$ collapse, both of which are believed to be unlikely.

Turning now to the $\mathsf{BQP}$ complexity class, noting the fact that FACTORING is both in $\mathsf{NP}$ with witnesses being the factors, and in $\mathsf{BQP}$ by Shor's algorithm, a conclusion is that FACTORING is *not* likely to be (promise) $\mathsf{BQP}$-complete.  If FACTORING were complete for $\mathsf{BQP}$ then, for example, $\mathsf{BQP}\subseteq\mathsf{NP}$, which may be ruled out by the recent breakthrough of [Raz and Tal](https://www.quantamagazine.org/finally-a-problem-that-only-quantum-computers-will-ever-be-able-to-solve-20180621/).

Thus it may be natural to ask:

> What is stopping FACTORING from being complete for $\mathsf{BQP}$?

GRAPH-ISOMORPHISM can be generalized/altered to SUBGRAPH-ISOMORPHISM, which is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete. Can FACTORING be generalized or altered in any way such that it is complete for $\mathsf{BQP}$, in much the same way that SUBGRAPH-ISOMORPHISM generalizes GRAPH-ISOMORPHISM to be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete?

Comment: I think because FACTORING lies in FBQP. I know that anything in FBQP is also in BQP, but it don't seems right that factoring (which is a function problem) is complete for class of decision problems (i.e. BQP). Because I don't see in the literature any function problem that is complete for a decision class of problems (see complete problems for classes such as NP, PSPACE, PH, etc., all complete problems are decision problems).

Comment: Thanks, that's reasonable to ask about, but it's also my understanding that it's straightforward to convert FACTORING to a decision problem, and then I can ask why that decision version of FACTORING is unlikely to be complete for BQP.  For example, one "decision" variant of FACTORING would be to decide whether $N$ has a prime factor between two given bounds $L$ and $U$ (given as binary strings).  My question then would be, can we convert this decision problem to one that's BQP-complete?  I might consider editing the question to emphasize this decision variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a rigorous level, nothing is necessarily stopping any of these things, because no one can even prove that P≠PSPACE.   If P=PSPACE, then every problem in P is BQP-complete as well as NP-complete, PSPACE-complete, etc.  So, any statement of the sort that you are looking for has to rest on conjectures about the structure of complexity classes.

In fact, there is a quantum hierarchy which addresses the complexity of factoring, and which is (very) loosely analogous to the classical polynomial hierarchy.  Namely, the [Fourier hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:F#fh).  Factoring is in the second level of the Fourier hierarchy using the Shor-Kitaev algorithm.  As the Complexity Zoo says, it is an open problem to find an oracle that makes FH infinite.  (As far as I know, it is still open.)  Nonetheless, I would be very surprised if FH collapses.

Comment: thanks! I find the second paragraph quite insightful to me. I just read the Y. SHI(2003) paper. I think the conjecture of the non-collapsibility of the Fourier hierarchy implies P and BPP are distinct classes. Quite the opposite of what people 'believe', i.e., P=BPP (conjecture).

Comment: As far as I know, P = BPP (which everyone believes) does not imply that FH collapses.  The Complexity Zoo is a bit confusing on one point:  It gives only the classical decision problem reduction of FH rather than what you could think of full FH, as a class of unitary operators.  If two terms in the classical simplication of a quantum complexity hierarchy are equal, it does not imply that the whole hierarchy collapses.

Comment: Point taken. Now, I see why P=BPP doesn't imply a total collapse of FH.

Comment: @Manish, for the same reasons as most people believe P=BPP, I think most people believe AM=NP, and yet we always talk about graph non-isomorphism (which has the famous AM protocol using hash functions) as being in the second level of the Polynomial Hierarchy.