# Are there any quantum algorithms conjectured to give an exponential speedup for a non-oracle problem that don't use the Quantum Fourier Transform?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-fourier-transform, speedup

The Quantum Fourier Transform (QFT) subroutine seems ubiquitous in most quantum algorithms that are conjectured to give an exponential (or at least superpolynomial) speedup over the best classical algorithms for the same classical (non-oracle, non-promise) problem, such as Shor's algorithm, the HHL algorithm, and using the phase estimation algorithm for simulating quantum systems.

Are there any classical non-oracle non-promise problems for which a known quantum algorithm is believed to give an exponential (or superpolynomial) advantage over the best classical algorithm, which *doesn't* use the QFT as a subroutine? Ideally, I'd prefer a problem of practical real-world interest, but I'd also accept a problem that was constructed solely to prove a complexity-theoretic result. Oracle problems and promise problems are out of scope.

The answer to this question may be somewhat subjective, in that it depends on whether a close variant of the traditional QFT "counts". I'll say that for the purpose of this question, a valid algorithm can't use anything "like" the QFT as a subroutine, although I admit that there may be somewhat some subjectivity in just what quantum subroutines are considered to be "like" the QFT. (The Hadamard transform is perhaps a [borderline case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform#Relation_to_Fourier_transform); I'll accept an algorithm that uses the Hadamard transformation, but would prefer one that doesn't.)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Aaronson-Ambainis conjecture? That conjecture puts a bit of a constraint on the structure required for exponential speedups of certain problems. This structure is often what’s exploited in QFT-based algorithms. But the AA conjecture is limited to NP decision problems, and certain search problems, or even non-NP problems, may avoid the AA conjecture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Aharonov–Jones–Landau algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Jones%E2%80%93Landau_algorithm) is a polynomial time quantum algorithm that approximates the #P-hard problem of evaluating the Jones polynomial at certain roots of unity. The best classical algorithm for this problem is exponential.

The original paper<sup>[[1](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.quant-ph/0511096)]</sup> stated that:

> "It does so not by using the Fourier transform, but instead, by exploiting a certain structure of the problem and encoding it into the nature of the unitary gates being used"

Comment: IIRC this algorithm is BQP complete, isn't it? So this is the absolute strongest contender one could have for an exponential speed-up. As strongly as we believe quantum computers have some speedup, this algorithm exhibits it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that problem - is the output a complex number? (Or more precisely, some finite-bit approximation of a complex number, where the algorithm runtime is polynomial in the desired number of bits of precision for the exact solution? Is that what "approximates" means in this context?)

Comment: Are there any (non-oracle) *decision* problems with a conjectured exponential quantum speedup with an algorithm that doesn't use the QFT?

Comment: @tparker the standard way to convert such problems into decision problems is to add a promise on the range of possible outputs. This is what’s meant by promise-BQP complete. Here we promise that we can only calculate the Jones polynomial up to a particular accuracy. It’s still a decision problem.

Comment: @MarkSpinelli This is just semantics, but I thought that the term "decision problem" was defined to exclude promise problems (with nontrivial promise). Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem) that "a promise problem is a generalization of a decision problem." Am I correct that this Jones polynomial problem is not in BQP, but instead is in promise-BQP? I would say that that's because class BQP applies to decision problems and class promise-BQP applies to promise problems.

Comment: @tparker I'll be honest and shame on me, I don't know which is formally correct (*e.g.*, whether BQP$\subseteq$promise-BQP or promise-BQP$\subseteq$BQP, or neither).  Certainly the Jones polynomial problem can be recast to "decide" whether the evaluation of the polynomial is greater than $a$ or less than $b$, *under the promise* that it is one of the two.  There's also "total" problems (with vacuous promises).

Comment: @tparker Promise versus non-promise classes are semantics that's elided over in the literature, but it can certainly make a lot of difference if you aren't particular!  See also [this](https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v003a004/v003a004.pdf).  The preprint version of that paper didn't make the distinction between promise-BQP and BQP but by the time it was published the authors had added a paragraph or two to explain the difference.

Comment: ALJ algorithm uses [Hadamard test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_test_(quantum_computation)) to evaluate the real and imaginary components of Jones polynomial. When we say that this problem is PromiseBQP-complete, we mean the "decision version" of it.

Comment: @MarkSpinelli According to https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v003a004/v003a004.pdf and https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1180, BQP⊆promise-BQP.

Comment: @MarkSpinelli I'm not very good at the theory of computation - so I apologize if this is incorrect or imprecise - but my rough intuition for this fact is as follows. A promise problem is any pair of disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. A decision problem is a pair of disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose union equals $\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, the set of decision problems is a subset of the set of promise problems. So the set of decision problems that can be efficiently solved by a QC is a subset of the set of promise problems that can be efficiently solved by a QC.

Comment: @tparker that makes sense. I’ve also heard of “total problems” where the promise gap is empty or the promise is vacuous. For reasons that are beyond ken, some classes such as BQP or BPP or QMA, are thought not to have complete problems and that’s why we need to speak of the promiseBQP class. The AJS problem is to *decide* on the value of the Jones polynomial up to some accuracy, where the accuracy corresponds to the promised gap.

Answer (score 6):

If you (1) don't like oracle problems, (2) wish to have a total, non-promise problem that also has an NP-certificate, and (3) are hesitant to use the full QFT over $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ but can live with Hadamard gates over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, one option may be the $x^2\bmod N$ [hash](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-022-01643-7)-based proof of quantumness of Kahanamoku-Meyer *et al.*.  This is an interactive proof using trapdoor hashes and includes other features that you might not like, but at least it's non-oracular and not based on a promise, and is conjectured to provide an exponential speedup (while using the Hadamard transform in lieu of a QFT).  Whether this is *useful* for anything other than proving quantumness or certifiable randomness generation is unknown.

I think of this as a "simpler" version of Shor's algorithm, in that with Kahanamoku-Meyer *et al.*, we calculate  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum|x\rangle|x^2\bmod N\rangle$ in superposition and apply Hadamard gates to the first register.  While, in Shor's algorithm, we calculate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum|x\rangle |a^x\bmod N\rangle$ in superposition and apply the full quantum Fourier transform to the first register.  Calculating $a^x\bmod N$ is harder than calculating $x^2\bmod N$, and calculating the full QFT over $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ is harder than doing a series of Hadamard gates.

With a hash such as $x^2\bmod N$ where $N$ is the product of two primes $p\times q$, upon measuring the second register $y$, doing the Hadamard transform on the first register gives a random string $d\ne\bf 0$ that is orthogonal to the bitwise sum/XOR of the two preimages $x_1$ and $x_2$ that satisfy $x_1^2\bmod N=x_2^2\bmod N=y$.  Finding such a string $d$ such that $d\cdot (x_1\oplus x_2)=0$ without knowing the factors of $N$ is conjectured to be exponentially difficult classically.

Answer (score 0):

I won't name an explicit example of an algorithm. But I will add a reason why a search for a ***QFT-less*** Quantum algorithm with superpolynomial speedup (w.r.t classical) might be extremely challenging.

(For generality, *I assume the Hadamard transform is a particular version of QFT*.)

Also, @trparker has mentioned in the last two lines of the post:

> (The Hadamard transform is perhaps a borderline case; I'll accept an algorithm that uses the Hadamard transformation, **but would prefer one that doesn't.**).

If you look at the paper by [Y. Shi(2003)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0312213), it mentions the Fourier Hierarchy ($FH$) in the *discussion* section. Informally, it gives an idea of why layers of QFT in an algorithm **could** provide a computational advantage over classical algorithms.

As quoted in [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:F#fh):

> $FH_k$ is the class of problems solvable by a uniform family of polynomial-size quantum circuits, with k levels of Hadamard gates and all other gates preserving the computational basis.

There is some consensus that FH is robust (or less likely to collapse). (See Greg Kuperberg's answer [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/37434/21801).)

Thus, getting rid of QFT (including Hadamard) and still getting quantum advantage **might** be intrinsically challenging.